# Can not see the node in JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I wonder if anyone can help, I have the following xml file, the problem is I can not see the third node 'food'.  I have created the files using JAXB there are four files have been created ObjectFactory, Breakfast-menu, foodType and food.  I can get to foodType from Breakfast-menu and see the name(fresh and frozen) but not 'food' and it's content.  can some please give some ideas.
thanks

```
<Breakfast-menu>
    <foodType>
        <name>fresh</name>
        <food name="Milk">
            <price>2</price>
        </food>
        <food name="Pears">
            <price>3</price>
        </food>
        <food name="Apples">
            <price>1</price>
        </food>
    </foodType>
    <foodType>
        <name>frozen</name>
        <food name="Fish">
            <price>2</price>
        </food>
        <food name="chips">
            <price>1</price>
        </food>
    </foodType>
</Breakfast-menu>
```

Java

```java
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("food");
              Unmarshaller u = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

              BreakfastMenu bM = (BreakfastMenu) u.unmarshal( 
                      new FileInputStream( "C:\\Users\\food.xml" ));
              List<FoodType> tType = bM.getFoodType();                
              for (FoodType tT : tType) {
                System.out.println("\t" + tT.getFood());

              }
```

Comment: What does the XML schema that you used to generate the JAXB model look like?  How are you creating your `JAXBContext` on the generated model?  Since this is a simple XML document have you considered starting from Java objects?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't make myself clear above, I can see 'food' node but NOT it's children (Price).

Comment: What does your class that maps to the `food` element look like?

Comment: http://www.logicalideas.co.uk/xml/Food.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this use case has a very simple XML document I would recommend starting from Java objects.

**BreakfastMenu**

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is configuration by exception so you only need to add annotations where you want the binding to differ from the default (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html).

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Breakfast-menu")
public class BreakfastMenu {

    private List<FoodType> foodType;

    public List<FoodType> getFoodType() {
        return foodType;
    }

    public void setFoodType(List<FoodType> foodType) {
        this.foodType = foodType;
    }

}
```

**FoodType**

By default the mappings are based on the public properties, but we can change JAXB to use fields with the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FoodType {

    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="food")
    private List<Food> foods;

}
```

**Food**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Food {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    private int price;

}
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BreakfastMenu.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14751166/input.xml");
        BreakfastMenu bm = (BreakfastMenu) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(bm, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Blaise, that was a great help.  I've managed to get it working.